# Recursion of Level Order Traversal of N-ary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree-traversal

I am currently working on N-ary trees and I stumbled upon Level Order Traversal. It seemed very easy on theory , not so difficult to run on code , but now I want to step it up and add recursion so I can wrap my head around it better. The things is I am now finding it very difficult to do so. There is my code for:

```
- The node class

    

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Implementation of a generic tree node containing the data and a list of children.
 *
 * @param <T> Generic type meant to implement reference types into the tree.
 */
public class Node<T> {
  private T data;
  private List<Node<T>> children;

  /**
   * Constructor that initializes the data and the list of children of the current node.
   *
   * @param data The value of the node.
   */
  public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
    children = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public T getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public List<Node<T>> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }

  public void setChildren(List<Node<T>> children) {
    this.children = children;
  }
}






-The tree class


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

/** Implementation of a generic n-ary tree. */
public class Tree<T> {
  private Node root;
  private List<Node<T>> nodes;
  /**
   * Constructor that initializes the root node of the tree.
   *
   * @param data The value of the root node.
   */
  public Tree(T data) {
    root = new Node<>(data);
  }

  public Node getRoot() {
    return root;
  }

  /**
   * Method that implements the Level Order Traversal algorithm. It's a left to right traverse where
   * each level of the tree is being printed out. First the root , then it's children and then each
   * child's children etc.
   *
   * @param root The root node of a tree.
   */
  public String levelOrderTraversal(Node root) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (root == null) {
      return "";
    }
    result.append("\n");
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(root);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
      int queueSize = q.size();
      while (queueSize > 0) {
        Node node = q.peek();
        q.remove();
        result.append(node.getData().toString()).append(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildren().size(); i++) {
          q.add((Node) node.getChildren().get(i));
        }
        queueSize--;
      }
      result.append("\n");
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  /**
   * This method serves to recursively move through and retrieve the nodes, so they can be printed
   * out to the user.
   *
   * @param root The root node of the tree.
   */
  private void walkThroughElements(Node root) {
    if (root == null) {
      return;
    }
    nodes.add(root);
    for (Object node : root.getChildren()) {
      walkThroughElements((Node) node);
    }
  }
  /**
   * Implementation of pre-order traversal of a generic tree. This traversal visit the root node
   * first , prints it , then visits the whole left sub-tree (the list of every child node), prints
   * every node and then traverses the right sub-tree , prints the nodes and ends the algorithm.
   *
   * @param root The root node of the tree.
   * @return The nodes of the tree as a string.
   */
  private String preOrderTraversal(Node<T> root) {
    nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    walkThroughElements(root);
    for (Node node : nodes) {
      result.append(node.getData()).append(" ");
    }
    result.setLength(result.length() - 1);
    return result.toString();
  }

  public String preOrderTraversal() {
    return preOrderTraversal(root);
  }
}
```

Is there an efficient way or does it even make sense to run this level order traversal method recursively?

This is the level order code after some changes

```
    public String levelOrderTraversal(Node root) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (root == null) {
      return "";
    }
    result.append("\n");
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(root);
    collectNodes(root, root.getChildren());
    result.append(root.getData().toString()).append(" ");
    result.append("\n");
    return result.toString();
  }
```

It gives the error on the line where collectNodes is called.

This is what collectNodes() looks like.

```
    private void collectNodes(Node<T> node, List<Node<T>> nodes) {
    nodes.add(node);
    for (Object child : node.getChildren()) {
      collectNodes((Node) child, nodes);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I assume you're asking whether it makes sense to convert your non-recursive `levelOrderTraversal()` to recursive? Sure, it can make sense and might be easier to read anyway. I'd not bother about efficiency until you really run into problems though, the differences here shouldn't be that big. Note that your recursive `walkThroughElements()` could be converted to "level-order" or "breadth-first" by first adding all children to the list before calling the method recursively.

Comment: @Thomas Yes , exactly! But I couldn't really get the whole converting walkThroughElements() to level-order , do you mind extending your explanation a little bit because I am kinda slow on recursion unfortunately. :)

Comment: You're calling `collectNodes(root, root.getChildren());` which is using the list of children as the result and thus you're iterating over that list _and_ modify it by adding elements. Instead, create a new list and pass it to that call and after that build your result string from that new list, i.e. `List<Node<T>> collectedNodes = new ArrayList<>(); collectNodes(root, collectedNodes ); /*now use collectedNodes to build the string*/`.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah that seemed to work but that kinda works exactly like Pre-order , I guess I have to look around to fix that now

Comment: Yes, your code would be a depth-first approach. If you want breadth-first you need to add the children first (and only the children, not the node itself) and then do the recursive call.

Comment: Do you mean like add some children to the root node and then run the call ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236842/discussion-between-jebvam-ust-and-thomas).

Comment: No, add a node's children to the result list first, then go down. Have a look at the bread-first recursive example in my answer.

Comment: @Thomas That's exactly what I'm trying and what I need but can't work it for some reason

Comment: You might want to have a close look the code and compare my example to your code. Note that bread-first recursion has a separate method that handles the root node. The recursive code you've posted so far is doing depth-first.

Comment: @Thomas If I wish to return the result using StringBuilder (It's mandatory) , should I put the StringBuilder in the collect() method?

Comment: You _could_ do that (just try) or you first gather the list of nodes in the order you need and then iterate over that list to build the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Thomas Doing that ends up in everything showing up as in DFS, that's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong, i.e. you're still using DFS to populate the list (as per the code you've posted). I'll enter chat for a couple of minutes (don't have that much time) so please show your code there. I'll also clean up my comments afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve those iteration problems using iteration (e.g. via a stack) or recursion. Let's use a method that gathers nodes much like your `walkThroughElements()`:

**Depth-first**

*Recursion*

```
//add the node and then go deeper
void collect(Node node, Collection<Node> nodes) {
  nodes.add(node);

  for(Node child : node.getChildren()) {
    collect(child, nodes);
  }
}
```

*Iteration*

```
class Level {
  final Node node;
  Iterator<Node> childItr;

  //constructor, setters, getters
}

void collect(Collection<Node> nodes) {
  Stack<Level> levels = new Stack<>();

  nodes.add(root);
  levels.push(new Level(root, root.getChildren().iterator()));

  while( !levels.isEmpty() ) {
    Level currentLevel = levels.peek();
    
    //remove the current level as it doesn't have any more children
    if( !currentLevel.childItr.hasNext() ) {
      levels.pop();
    } else {
      //get the next child and add it to the result
      Node child = currentLevel.childItr.next();
      nodes.add(child);

      //go down to the child's level
      levels.push(new Level(child, child.getChildren().iterator())
    }
  }
}
```

**Breadth-first**

*Recursion*

```
//add the children first (i.e. the entire level) and then go deeper
void collectChildren(Node node, Collection<Node> nodes) {      
  for(Node child : node.getChildren()) {
    nodes.add(child);
    collectChildren(child, nodes);
  }
}

//special case: root node
void collect(Collection<Node> nodes) {
   nodes.add(root);
   collectChildren(root, nodes);
}
```

*Iteration*

```
void collect(Collection<Node> nodes) {
  Queue<Node> nodesToProcess = new LinkedList<>();

  nodesToProcess.add(root);

  while( !nodesToProcess.isEmpty() ) {
    Node node = nodesToProcess.poll();

    nodes.add(node);

    nodesToProcess.addAll(node.getChildren());
  }
}
```

As you can see, recursion is easier on depth-first than breadth-first but easy to read anyway. Recursion will use the call stack to maintain state so it takes up (non-heap) memory and also has limits to its depth (depends on how much memory there is but the infamous StackOverflowException would tell you there's either a bug or the tree is too deep).

Iteration is easier with breadth first and requires additional constructs like a stack or a queue. It requires some heap memory for those constructs and *may* be faster due to some optimizations but in general I'd not bother about performance differences here as they should only manifest themselves for really large trees - and in that case recursion might hit the call stack limit already.

Comment: Thank you , I feel like I have some understanding on the issue now , I will try to implement this in my code and come back to show what's going on.

Comment: Is ConcurrentModificationException normal while using this?

Comment: @JebvamUst no, this is not normal. This normally happens when iterating using an iterator (or "for each") and modifying the same collection within the body (could be in another method call). Are you changing the collection of children during iteration by any chance?

Comment: No , I don't think I am , just getting the children and adding them to the nodes list.

Comment: @JebvamUst well, it's hard to tell without seeing some code. Could you add it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion typically will be slower than iteration and use more stack space as well.But Yes,this can also be solved using recursive way(DFS approach).

For your reference : https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/discuss/33562/Java-1ms-DFS-recursive-solution-and-2ms-BFS-iterative-solution

Comment: Yeah I have seen such solutions here and there but the thing is I do not have a left and right pointer in my Node class , is it possible to do it recursively without actually having those two or are they mandatory ?

Comment: @JebvamUst In fact you do have these pointers in your class though without a reprsentation of their own: Given some `Node` instance `n`, use `n.children.get(0)` for `left` and `n.children.get(n.children.size()-1)` for `right`, resp. (checks and edge cases omitted).

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to do it in a lazy way

```
// assume not null Node::data (if so, wrap into Optional or similar)
static <T> Stream<T> levelOrderTraversal(Node<T> tree) {

    final List<Node<T>> fifo = new ArrayList<>();

    if(tree != null)
        fifo.add(tree);

    final Function<T, T> next = o -> {
        if(fifo.isEmpty())
            return null; // End Of Stream
        Node<T> x = fifo.remove(0);
        System.out.println("++++++ " + x.data);
        if(x.children != null)
            fifo.addAll(x.children);
        return x.data;
    };

    return Stream.iterate(null, next::apply).skip(1).takeWhile(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

for example

```
++++++ foo
foo
++++++ bar1
bar1
++++++ bar2
bar2
++++++ par11
par11
++++++ par12
par12
++++++ par21
par21
++++++ par22
par22
++++++ subA
subA
++++++ subB
subB
```

where you only mantain the intermediate traversing level (not the whole tree).

For example, if you log every node expansion and filter the tree, not all nodes are logged

```
    levelOrderTraversal(tree)
            .takeWhile(x -> !x.equals("bar2"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

only expand the `foo`, `bar1` and `bar2` nodes

```
++++++ foo
foo
++++++ bar1
bar1
++++++ bar2
```